# Identify the geometric transformations that get, from a complex number z, the images of $\overline{z}$,$i\overline{z}$ and $\overline{z}/i$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

> Consider a complex number z.
>
> Identify the geometric transformations that get, from a complex number
> z, the geometric images of $\overline{z}$,$i\overline{z}$ and
> $\overline{z}/i$

- $\overline{z}$

If z is $x+yi$ then $\overline{z}=x-yi$ which means that z gets inverted by the x axis. However, my book states the solution is

> rotation of $-\pi/2$, with center at the origin of the referential.

How do I get to that conclusion?

- $i\overline{z}$

I tried:

$i\overline{z} = i(x-yi) = xi+y$

My book states the solution is

> Identity.

And that's just it. What does my book mean by this? Being an identity shouldn't it be equal to $z$? Could anyone explain this to me?

- $\frac{\overline{z}}{i}$

I tried:

$$\frac{\overline{z}}{i} = \frac{(x-yi)\cdot -i}{i \cdot -i} = -(ix+y^2) = -ix-y^2$$

My book states the solution is

> rotation of $-\pi$ with center at the origin of the referential.

How do I get to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation $z \rightarrow \overline{z}$ can be represented by a reflection in the real axis. I'm not sure what 'referential' means in your book.

The transformation $z \rightarrow i \overline{z}$ is a reflection in the line $re(z) = im(z)$. See diagram below.

Your calculation for last part is incorrect, it should be

$$
\frac{\overline{z}}{i} = 
\frac{(x-iy)}{i}
=
\frac{xi + y}{i^2}
=
-xi - y
$$

The transformation for this can be viewed as $z \rightarrow (i\overline{z}) \times -1$, a reflection in the line $re(z) = im(z)$ followed by a half turn around the origin. Alternatively, a reflection in the line $re(z) = -im(z)$.

Here is a diagram that might help

[image]